# Unspecified Error with Cached Image

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I am creating a HTML5 game using canvas. In IE, I am getting random unspecified errors when drawing some images to the canvas. The first time I play the game, the images display without any issues.

On the second time around, the drawImage throws an unspecified error. I looked at the network and it says the following:

`Method:Get, Result:304, Type:image/png, Received:174B, Taken:<1 ms, Initiator:<img>`

I looked at the response body and it says "***This data could not be rendered.***" I look at another image that also was requested at the same time, but that worked.

It has all the same information except the response body displays the image. This doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome. Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

UPDATE:

```
Game.GenerateSpriteObject = function(obj){
  var key = "";
  if (obj.x !== undefined){ //Sprite
        key = obj.href + obj.x + obj.y + obj.width + obj.height;
    }else{//Animated Sprite
        key = obj.href + obj.startX + obj.startY + obj.width + obj.height + obj.imagesPerRow + obj.imageCount;
    }
  if (Game.cachedSprites[key] === undefined){
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = obj.href;
    imageObj.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    if (obj.x !== undefined){ //Sprite
        Game.cachedSprites[key] = new Sprite(imageObj, obj.x, obj.y, obj.width, obj.height);
    }else{//Animated Sprite
        Game.cachedSprites[key] = new AnimatedSpriteSheet(imageObj, obj.startX, obj.startY, obj.width, obj.height, obj.imagesPerRow, obj.imageCount);
    }
  }
  return Game.cachedSprites[key];
};

function Sprite(img, x, y, width, height){
  this.img = img;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height =height;
}

function AnimatedSpriteSheet(img, startX, startY, width, height, imagesPerRow, imageCount){
  this.img = img;
  this.startX = startX;
  this.startY = startY;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.imagesPerRow = imagesPerRow;
  this.imageCount = imageCount;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that downloads the image(s). Sounds like you've got image corruption.

Comment: @markE, I have added the code.

Comment: @dburgener, was there ever a resolution to this?

Comment: @NDavis no resolution yet. Just said that the game wouldn't fully work on IE.

Comment: @dburgener, any way you could post the full source of the game? I'm experiencing a similar issue and would like to see if it's related

Comment: @NDavis Unfortunately I can't. The code belongs to my customer.